# Execute automatically "Convert JSON to YAML" at start of Swagger Editor

Tags: json, api, swagger, openapi, swagger-editor

I am invoking a swagger json object per `spec.js` inside `SwaggerEditorBundle` to read local swagger api docs.

The swagger json code is bad formatting in one line inside Swagger Editor, so I need to click on *Editor -> Convert JSON to YAML* to enforce pretty formatting in YAML-style.

How to execute the javascript function automatically for *Convert JSON to YAML* after reading of spec.js to ensure always pretty formatting in YAML-style?

**index.html**

```
  <script src="./dist/swagger-editor-bundle.js"> </script>
  <script src="./dist/swagger-editor-standalone-preset.js"> </script>
  <script src="./dist/spec.js"> </script>
  <script>
  window.onload = function() {
    const editor = SwaggerEditorBundle({
      spec: spec,
      dom_id: '#swagger-editor',
      layout: 'StandaloneLayout',
      presets: [
        SwaggerEditorStandalonePreset
      ]
    })

    window.editor = editor
  }
  </script>
```

**spec.js**

```
var spec = {
  "consumes": [
    "application/json"
  ],
  "info": {
    "title": "Simple API overview",
    "version": "v2"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/": {
      "get": {
        "operationId": "listVersionsv2",
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "200 300 response",
            "examples": {
              "application/json": "{\n    \"versions\": [\n        {\n            \"status\": \"CURRENT\",\n            \"updated\": \"2011-01-21T11:33:21Z\",\n            \"id\": \"v2.0\",\n            \"links\": [\n                {\n                    \"href\": \"http://127.0.0.1:8774/v2/\",\n                    \"rel\": \"self\"\n                }\n            ]\n        },\n        {\n            \"status\": \"EXPERIMENTAL\",\n            \"updated\": \"2013-07-23T11:33:21Z\",\n            \"id\": \"v3.0\",\n            \"links\": [\n                {\n                    \"href\": \"http://127.0.0.1:8774/v3/\",\n                    \"rel\": \"self\"\n                }\n            ]\n        }\n    ]\n}"
            }
          }
        },
        "summary": "List API versions"
      }
    },
  },
  "swagger": "2.0"
}
```